# 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Player

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I was trying to code the code below into a package that came from a tutorial, but it originally had it in the timeline

now it gives the error 1180: Call to a possibly undefined method Player.

here is a snippet from the concerning code (full code is below that)

```
private var player:Player;

    public function RamboCat() 
    {

    player = new Player();
```

So Player is not defined. Does this mean it's missing a AS file or something
But i'm trying to tell flash to use a image (image is instanced 'player')

i added the above code (minus the public function that already existed) because i found
a source which explained i should add those: http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=268065

my experience with  "package" and "import" things is a bit low. So hopefully you can help.

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.geom.Point;

public class RamboCat extends MovieClip 
{
    var leftPressed:Boolean = false;
    var rightPressed:Boolean = false;
    var upPressed:Boolean = false;
    var downPressed:Boolean = false;

    var leftBumping:Boolean = false;
    var rightBumping:Boolean = false;
    var upBumping:Boolean = false;
    var downBumping:Boolean = false;

    var leftBumpPoint:Point = new Point(-30, -55);
    var rightBumpPoint:Point = new Point(30, -55);
    var upBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, -120);
    var downBumpPoint:Point = new Point(0, 0);

    var scrollX:Number = 0;
    var scrollY:Number = 500;

    var xSpeed:Number = 0;
    var ySpeed:Number = 0;

    var speedConstant:Number = 4;
    var frictionConstant:Number = 0.9;
    var gravityConstant:Number = 1.8;
    var jumpConstant:Number = -35;
    var maxSpeedConstant:Number = 18;

    var doubleJumpReady:Boolean = false;
    var upReleasedInAir:Boolean = false;

    var keyCollected:Boolean = false;
    var doorOpen:Boolean = false;

    var currentLevel:int = 1;

    var animationState:String = "idle";

    var bulletList:Array = new Array();
    var enemyList:Array = new Array();
    var bumperList:Array = new Array();

    private var player:Player;

    public function RamboCat() 
    {


    player = new Player();

    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDownHandler);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUpHandler);

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop);

    addEnemiesToLevel1();
    addBumpersToLevel1();
    }
    public function addEnemiesToLevel1():void
{
addEnemy(620, -115);
addEnemy(900, -490);
addEnemy(2005, -115);
addEnemy(1225, -875);
}

    public function addBumpersToLevel1():void
{
addBumper(500, -115);
addBumper(740, -115);
}


    public function loop(e:Event):void{
if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + leftBumpPoint.x, player.y + leftBumpPoint.y, true)){
    //trace("leftBumping");
    leftBumping = true;
} else {
    leftBumping = false;
}

if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + rightBumpPoint.x, player.y + rightBumpPoint.y, true)){
    //trace("rightBumping");
    rightBumping = true;
} else {
    rightBumping = false;
}

if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + upBumpPoint.x, player.y + upBumpPoint.y, true)){
    //trace("upBumping");
    upBumping = true;
} else {
    upBumping = false;
}

if(back.collisions.hitTestPoint(player.x + downBumpPoint.x, player.y + downBumpPoint.y, true)){
    //trace("downBumping");
    downBumping = true;
} else {
    downBumping = false;
}   


if(leftPressed){
    xSpeed -= speedConstant;
    player.scaleX = -1;

} else if(rightPressed){
    xSpeed += speedConstant;
    player.scaleX = 1;
}

 /*if(upPressed){
ySpeed -= speedConstant;

} else if(downPressed){
ySpeed += speedConstant;

}*/

if(leftBumping){
    if(xSpeed < 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(rightBumping){
    if(xSpeed > 0){
        xSpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(upBumping){
    if(ySpeed < 0){
        ySpeed *= -0.5;
    }
}

if(downBumping){ //if we are touching the floor
    if(ySpeed > 0){ 
        ySpeed = 0; //set the y speed to zero
    }
    if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
        ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
    }

    //DOUBLE JUMP
    if(upReleasedInAir == true){
        upReleasedInAir = false;
    }
    if(doubleJumpReady == false){
        doubleJumpReady = true;
    }
} else { //if we are not touching the floor

    ySpeed += gravityConstant; //accelerate downwards

    //DOUBLE JUMP
    if(upPressed == false && upReleasedInAir == false){
        upReleasedInAir = true;
        //trace("upReleasedInAir");
    }
    if(doubleJumpReady && upReleasedInAir){
        if(upPressed){ //and if the up arrow is pressed
            //trace("doubleJump!");
            doubleJumpReady = false;
            ySpeed = jumpConstant; //set the y speed to the jump constant
        }
    }

}

if(keyCollected == false){
    if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.doorKey)){
        back.other.doorKey.visible = false;
        keyCollected = true;
        trace("key collected");
    }
}

if(doorOpen == false){
    if(keyCollected == true){
        if(player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)){
            back.other.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(2);
            doorOpen = true;
            trace("door open");
        }
    }
}


if(xSpeed > maxSpeedConstant){ //moving right
    xSpeed = maxSpeedConstant;
} else if(xSpeed < (maxSpeedConstant * -1)){ //moving left
    xSpeed = (maxSpeedConstant * -1);
}

xSpeed *= frictionConstant;
ySpeed *= frictionConstant;

if(Math.abs(xSpeed) < 0.5){
    xSpeed = 0;
}

scrollX -= xSpeed;
scrollY -= ySpeed;

back.x = scrollX;
back.y = scrollY;

sky.x = scrollX * 0.2;
sky.y = scrollY * 0.2;

if( ( leftPressed || rightPressed || xSpeed > speedConstant || xSpeed < speedConstant *-1 ) && downBumping){
    animationState = "running";
} else if(downBumping){
    animationState = "idle";
} else {
    animationState = "jumping";
}

if(player.currentLabel != animationState){
    player.gotoAndStop(animationState);
}


if (enemyList.length > 0) // if there are any enemies left in the enemyList
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i < enemyList.length; i++) // for each enemy in the enemyList
    {
        if (bulletList.length > 0) // if there are any bullets alive
        {
            for (var j:int = 0; j < bulletList.length; j++) // for each bullet in the bulletList
            {
                if ( enemyList[i].hitTestObject(bulletList[j]) )
                {
                    trace("Bullet and Enemy are colliding");
                    enemyList[i].removeSelf();
                    bulletList[j].removeSelf();
                }

                // enemyList[i] will give you the current enemy
                // bulletList[j] will give you the current bullet
                // this will check all combinations of bullets and enemies
                // and see if any are colliding
            }
        }
    }
}

 //corralling the bad guys with bumpers
if (enemyList.length > 0){ //enemies left in the enemyList?
    for (var k:int = 0; k < enemyList.length; k++){ // for each enemy in the enemyList
        if (bumperList.length > 0){
            for (var h:int = 0; h < bumperList.length; h++){ // for each bumper in the List
                if ( enemyList[k].hitTestObject(bumperList[h]) ){
                    enemyList[k].changeDirection();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

 //player and enemy collisions
if (enemyList.length > 0){ //enemies left?
    for (var m:int = 0; m < enemyList.length; m++){ // for each enemy in the enemyList
        if ( enemyList[m].hitTestObject(player) ){
            trace("player collided with enemy");
            //code to damage player goes here, maybe integrate with a health bar?                           
            enemyList[m].removeSelf();
        }
    }
}

 }

    public function nextLevel():void{
currentLevel++;
trace("Next Level: " + currentLevel);
if(currentLevel == 2){
   gotoLevel2();
}
// can be extended...
// else if(currentLevel == 3) { gotoLevel3(); } // etc, etc.    
}

    public function gotoLevel2():void{
back.other.gotoAndStop(2);
back.visuals.gotoAndStop(2);
back.collisions.gotoAndStop(2);
scrollX = 0;
scrollY = 500;

keyCollected = false;
back.other.doorKey.visible = true;
doorOpen = false;
back.other.lockedDoor.gotoAndStop(1);
}

    public function keyDownHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
    leftPressed = true;

} else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
    rightPressed = true;

} else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
    upPressed = true;

} else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
    downPressed = true;
    if(doorOpen && player.hitTestObject(back.other.lockedDoor)){
        //proceed to the next level if the player is touching an open door
        nextLevel();
    }
}
}

    public function keyUpHandler(e:KeyboardEvent):void{
if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT){
    leftPressed = false;

} else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT){
    rightPressed = false;

} else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.UP){
    upPressed = false;

} else if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN){
    downPressed = false;
}

if(e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE){
    fireBullet();
}
 }

    public function fireBullet():void
{
var playerDirection:String;
if(player.scaleX < 0){
    playerDirection = "left";
} else if(player.scaleX > 0){
    playerDirection = "right";
}
var bullet:Bullet = new Bullet(player.x - scrollX, player.y - scrollY, playerDirection, xSpeed);
back.addChild(bullet);

bullet.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved);
bulletList.push(bullet);

 }

    public function bulletRemoved(e:Event):void
 {
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, bulletRemoved); //this just removes the eventListener so we don't get an error
bulletList.splice(bulletList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1); 
 //this removes 1 object from the bulletList, at the index of whatever object caused this function to activate
 }

    public function addEnemy(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void
 {
var enemy:Enemy = new Enemy(xLocation, yLocation);
back.addChild(enemy);
enemy.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
enemyList.push(enemy);
 }

    public function addBumper(xLocation:int, yLocation:int):void
 {
var bumper:Bumper = new Bumper(xLocation, yLocation);
back.addChild(bumper);
bumper.visible = false;
bumperList.push(bumper);
 }

    public function enemyRemoved(e:Event):void
 {
e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, enemyRemoved);
  //this just removes the eventListener so it doesn't give an error
enemyList.splice(enemyList.indexOf(e.currentTarget), 1); //this removes 1 object from the enemyList, at the index of whatever object caused this function to activate
 }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It cannot be a reference to an instance of player as: `new Player();` creates a new instance of Player.

So Player needs to be a class. If you are using Adobe Flash Professional, you can right click the image in the library, click properties, actionscript tab, then export to actionscript (make sure the class is called Player). this will create the class for the image for you.

If you are not using Adobe flash professional, then let me know and I will help with the IDE you are using.

Edit: And looking back you will also need to import Keyboard Class if you have not done already.

Comment: yeah this was the problem. BTW do i remove                            player = new Player();  and private var player:Player;                I do get a diffrent error now:5006: An ActionScript file can not have more than one externally visible definition: DocumentClass, onRequestStart

Comment: i fixed the 5006 but do i need to remove the player = new Player(); and private var player:Player;

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need an import statement for Player.

To import a single class:

```
import your.package.name.ClassName;
```

To import every class in a package:

```
import your.package.name.*;
```

So you need:

```
import xxx.Player;
```

where xxx is the package where Player class sits.